# How to send keys to an element like <textarea name="body" placeholder="Start typing..."

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have the below element:

```
<textarea name="body" placeholder="Start typing..." tabindex="0" pwa2-uuid="EDITOR-C10-C4D-8CC58-82F" pwa-fake-editor="" spellcheck="false" style="white-space: pre-wrap !important; position: relative !important; z-index: auto !important; line-height: 18.9px; font-size: 14px; background: transparent !important; height: 43px;">MOSTEC</textarea>
```

where 'MOSTEC' is the variable that I want to type and send. This is the code I have so far:

```
def send_comment(message):
    textarea.send_keys(message)
    textarea.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    return

textarea = driver.find_element_by_name('body')

while True:
    send_comment(MOSTEC)
     time.sleep(3.5)
```

However I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

How would I be able to post a comment of the variable? Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me - You have to clear your `textarea` before writing anything in that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("Your URL")

textarea = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@name='body']")))

textarea.clear()
textarea.send_keys("This is for test")
textarea.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error message means that the ChromeDriver was unable to locate the desired element 'body' in the Browsing Context i.e. Browser session. I would try to make sure that you can locate the 'body' element and confirm if it ought to be selected by the find_element_by_name() function.